# How can I make Java draw a shape based on input in percentage?

Tags: java

I would like to make it so the user inputs a percentage between 50-100% and a Swiss flag is drawn based on that percentage!
I don't need the exact code, just an explanation on how to do it and what I should include/exclude.

I am fairly new to this and have no idea how I'm supposed to make this happen.
Here is my code so far. This draws out the flag as it's supposed to be shown at 100%:
(Comment language is in Norwegian)

```
    //Lager Flagget
    makeWindow("Flagg", 500, 500);
    String innStr = getText ("Størelse i prosent(50-100):");



        //Setter blå bakgrunn
        setColor(135,206,250);
        fillRectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);

        //Lager en rød bakgrunn til flagget
        setColor(255, 0, 0);
        fillRectangle(100, 100, 300, 300);

        //Lager et hvit rektangel lodrett i midten av flagget
        setColor(255, 255, 255);
        fillRectangle(225, 175, 50, 150);

        //Lager et hvit rektangel vannrett i midten flagget
        setColor(255, 255, 255);
        fillRectangle(175, 225, 150, 50);
```

Edit: The flag is to be drawn in the middle of the window at all times!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to to define working coordinates with respect to the center of your window, then translate before drawing:

```
//Lager Flagget
    makeWindow("Flagg", 500, 500);
    String innStr = getText ("Størelse i prosent(50-100):");

   int pct = Int.parseInt(innStr)  ;

   int cX = 250 ; // Center of the window
   int cY = 250 ; // Center of the window
   int flagHmax = 300 ;
   int crossHmax = 150 ;
   int barWmax  = 50 ;

   flagH = flagHmax * pct / 100 ; // integer math
   crossH = crossHmax * pct / 100 ;
   barW = barWmax * pct / 100 ;


    //Setter blå bakgrunn
    setColor(135,206,250);
    fillRectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);

    //Lager en rød bakgrunn til flagget
    setColor(255, 0, 0);
    fillRectangle(cX - flagH/2, cY - flagH/2, flagH, flagH);

    //Lager et hvit rektangel lodrett i midten av flagget
    setColor(255, 255, 255);
    fillRectangle(cX - barW/2, cY - crossH/2, barW, crossH);

    //Lager et hvit rektangel vannrett i midten flagget
    setColor(255, 255, 255);
    fillRectangle(cX - crossH/2, cY - barW/2, crossH, barW) ;
```